# How to detect a user keyboard press while running a program within pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a small toy program that prompts the user to press any key in order to continue. When I run this within pycharm, pressing the key within the run window after the program prompts the user for input does not work

In which window do I have to press a key so that Python program can detect a key press to the pycharm. When I launch it from the command line, it is able to detect a key press.

I'm just using the following statement in code

```
    input("Press any key after deleting the folder manually...")
```

Comment: Your prompt should be available in the Console pane and should operate almost like running it through the command prompt - just focus on it and press enter.

Comment: You need to press Enter, not just any key, for `input` to return.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I was actually pressing the enter key twice. It looks like I have to press any other key and then press enter. If you can put this as an answer I will accept it